# Changing url with RewriteRule does not replace the url and redirects my page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am trying the following mod_rewrite code to change the url of my site to a different one, but it seems like if it is redirecting and I would like the page to load my targeted url.

Say I want to load url: **www.AAAAAA.com/store/index.php?categ=cars**
but in the URL bar I want to display the following:
**www.AAAAAA.com/store/cars**

My code is like this (but not working since it redirects and does not rewrite properly):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^store/(.*)$ store/index.php?categ=$1 [L]
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: mod_rewrite rewrites incoming requests, it does not adapt the existing links in your html. That's your job.

Comment: @mario I am not trying to adapt any existing links, just to rewrite the URL shown to users, just as many sites do

Comment: So, uh, have you changed *your* html to contain the new pretty urls or not?

Comment: mm nop. What kind of change should I do there? It's php that load dynamically depending on the 'categ' parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(store)/index\.php\?categ=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule ^store/(.+?)/?$ /store/index.php?categ=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: What URI did you try to test? And where is this .htaccess placed in your path?

Comment: 'http://www.ABCD.com/store/index.php?categ=headbands' and I am placing the htaccess in the main directory. But I still see the same URL in the top bar

Comment: Ah sorry there was an extra dangling slash before store in my code. Just edited it, try it now.

Comment: This one is working great. Would you mind quickly explaining what rule is doing what? I'm trying to follow the same model for another page...

Comment: 1st rule is for external redirection. `%{THE_REQUEST}` denotes original request as received by Apache. In that line I am capturing literal string `store` in `%1` and value of `categ` GET parameter (`headbands`) in `%2`. Then using RewriteRule I redirect to `/store/headbands`. `?` in the end is used to strip query string from URL.

Comment: 2nd rule is for internal forwarding. It matches and captures text after `/store/` in `$1` from URL and forwards the request to `/store/index.php?categ=$1`.

Comment: You might know the answer to my new question too :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326540/rewriting-url-that-contains-multiple-parameters-with-multi-word-strings-with-mo

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(store/images|store/css|store/js)($|/) - [L]
RewriteBase /store/
RewriteRule ^store/(.*)$  index.php?categ=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You can use line 3 to exclude any directories from rewriting, e.g. you wouldn't want a request for `domain.com/store/images/logo.jpg` to be rewritten.