# Rewriting URL that contains multiple parameters with multi-word strings (with mod_rewrite)

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Was trying to rewrite the URL of a page that has multiple parameters and one of the parameters contains multiple words (separated by spaces when submitted).

This would be the URL: **www.ABCD.com/store/itemsDescr.php?categ=headbands&id=123&name=brown%20with%20black**

I would like the URL to show like this:
www.ABCD.com/store/headbands/123/brown-with-black

I tried this, but it did not work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^categ=([^&]+) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &categ=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^store/itemsDescr\.php$ $0/%1

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &id=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^store/itemsDescr\.php/[^/]+$ $0/%1

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([^&]+) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &name=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^store/itemsDescr\.php/([^/]+/[^/]+)$ http://www.ABCD.com/store/$1/%1/? [L,QSA,NC]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

NOTE: Before this rule I want to implement, I already have this other rule for another page, in case it can create conflict:

```
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(store)/index\.php\?categ=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule ^store/(.+?)/?$ /store/index.php?categ=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: What do you mean by: `But I don't want to redirect.` ?

Comment: It's actually a typo. Deleting that. I just want the URL to look more SEO friendly...

Comment: Alright I will take a stab. (It is little more involved)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think my code above is way too complex for what I need, which is to rewrite with 3 parameters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^categ=([^&]+)&id=([^&]+)&name=([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(store)/itemsDescr\.php$ /$1/%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L,NC,NE]

RewriteRule ^(store)/([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)$ /$1/$2-$3 [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(store)/([^\s]+)\s(.+)$ /$1/$2-$3 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(store)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ /$1/itemsDescr.php?categ=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA,NC,NE]
```

Comment: mm... it's not loading the intended page anymore and neither changing the URL to the nice looking one.

Comment: Its a tested solution. did you try this URL: `http://www.ABCD.com/store/itemsDescr.php?categ=headbands&id=123&name=brown%20with%20black` or something else?

Comment: Yes, that's the URL. What it does is: it keeps the original ugly URL and it loads the page `www.ABCD.com/store/` not the `itemsDescr.php` one

Comment: oh! maybe it's because I had this other rule before? see post Edit

Comment: Yes first comment out all pre-existing stuff and test using above rules only and see if URL changes as your requirements.

Comment: Indeed, it changes the URL but does not load the original page I am targeting. It just tries to load the new nice URL (which does not really exist)

Comment: Which is good 1st step. Once we have good URL in browser its not difficult to make load content.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32505/discussion-between-samyb8-and-anubhava)